# how can get a tree with only one tree traversal?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

consider I want to transfer a binary tree in a serialised way and I have only one string to pass that tree and I can use the help of only one traversal, is there any way I could do that??  - (was asked to me in Ebay)..

in other words can a binary tree be generated by using only one tree traversal string?? the interviewer also gave me a hint by saying i can use null in place where leaf is absent..

Comment: i didnt quite understand the question. you would like to convert a binary tree object into a string?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... Just go through the tree, probably depth-first, and serialize contents. Then on the other end, reconstruct the tree.

Comment: **Preorder.** Store it using array indexes. so it can be decoded easily at the receiving side.

Comment: You can't uniquely decode a tree from its preorder traversal.  What tree is represented by "a b c"?

Comment: the string should be created using array indexes.

Comment: You don't get the question. This is an algorithmic, very restricted theoretic question and not a real-world problem. In theory, an arbitrary tree can only be encoded without ambiguities by two different traversal strings.

Comment: nice try @ Azodious but not the way i wanted it... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT] given that this seems to be some given task, not really a real-world problem, the answer didn't make sense. Second try:

Seeing that you can use null-values, you can indeed use preorder with null values.

`a b null null c null null` would be a tree that looks like `(a (b) (c))`, while `(a (b (c)) )` would be coded as `a b c null null null null` (note that i gave each leaf two null children, maybe it works without that)

Comment: See, i can just make the tree complete by using null-leaves. A complete tree shouldn't be problematic to encode using just a single traversal.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~csci133/fall05/trees-fig4.jpg

please consider above tree in above image, if we want to pass a string using only 1 traversal we can by putting special symbol whenever there is no child for that perticular location.

now if we pass 1 2 4 7 $ $ $ 5 $ $ 3 $ 6 8 $ $ 9 $ $

```
                                        1
                                     /      \
                                   2        3
                                  /  \     / \
                                 4    5   $   6
                                / \  / \     / \
                               7   $ $  $    8   9
                              / \           /\  /\
                             $  $          $ $ $ $
```

here $ means the child is null so move to the next location of the order.

please correct me if im wrong and above is impossible....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent any object in string, byte[] or streams you could have a look at JSON serialization or XML serialization.